# pandas select rows asof time, instead of datetime

Tags: pandas

Given a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 20, 40, 50,60,70,80,100]},index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-27 09:01:00','2018-02-27 09:02:00','2018-02-27 09:04:00','2018-02-27 09:05:00','2018-03-27 09:01:00','2018-03-27 09:02:00','2018-03-27 09:03:00','2018-03-27 09:05:00']))
```

I hope to get the values as of 09:04, in which case it should return 2 rows with 'a' value to be 40 and 80. It seems pandas only takes datetime as input for asof() and I have to do some pre-processing to create all the filters myself. 
I wonder if there is already such functionality in pandas where input like 09:04 would suffice, or other simple ways to get the result.

EDIT: 
Sorry I put in the wrong df in the beginning - there should not be 09:04 for the 2nd day, thus need asof().

Comment: Do you need `asof` because possible `40` and `90` for `09:04:30` ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using `strftime`

```
df[df.index.strftime('%H:%M')=='09:04']
Out[652]: 
                      a
2018-02-27 09:04:00  40
2018-03-27 09:04:00  90
```

Answer (score 1):

If need to disregard the seconds for a minute, can use `.between_time`

```
df.between_time('09:04', '09:05', include_end=False)
#                      a
#2018-02-27 09:04:00  40
#2018-03-27 09:04:00  90
```

Or if you want to make this a bit more functional:

```
time = '09:04'
df.between_time(time, (pd.to_datetime(time)+pd.Timedelta('1min')).time(), include_end=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using boolean index:

```
df[(df.index.hour == 9) & (df.index.minute == 4)]
```

Output:

```
                      a
2018-02-27 09:04:00  40
2018-03-27 09:04:00  90
```